# SQL XML Node Extraction

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, ssms

I am relatively new to work with XML data in SQL so please forgive any "silly" mistakes :p.

In essence what I am trying to do is, extract the "Before" & "After" values from the following XML:

```
<AuditData>
  <Field Name="BrandEmailSubscribed">
    <Before Value="True" />
    <After Value="False" />
  </Field>
  <Metadata Type="OperatorInstigated">
    <Note></Note>
  </Metadata>
</AuditData>
```

I have tried using the following SQL however this is returning a blank value (not NULL though).

```
select top 10 C.B.value('(Before)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),AD.* from Table AD
OUTER APPLY AD.Data.nodes('AuditData/Field') AS C(B)
```

Any help is much appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the attribute to be extracted

```
select top 10 C.B.value('(Before/@Value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'), AD.* 
from Table AD
OUTER APPLY AD.Data.nodes('AuditData/Field') AS C(B)
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this! That has worked a treat.
Certainly saving this in my notes for reference!!